# Subtract date in query

Tags: mongodb

My objective is to get all documents where the field "myDate" is older than the actual date minus one month.

I tried this :

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").find
(
    { "$and" :
        [
            {"myDate": {$ne:null} },
            {"myDate": {$lt: {$subtract: [ISODate(), 1000*60*60*24*30 /* 30 days */]} } }
        ]
    }
)
```

It seems to not working when I put instructions in the $lt. If I put only Date like below, it's work :

```
db.getCollection("ScheduledTasks").find
(
    { "$and" :
        [
            {"Context.Object.LastFilterDate": {$ne:null} },
            {"Context.Object.LastFilterDate": {$lt: ISODate() } }
        ]
    }
)
```

An example value of my field myDate is 2018-12-05T14:57:25.466+0000 and detected by Studio3T to Date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{ myDate: { $lt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30) } }
```

or in aggregation stage:

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $lt: ["$myDate", { $subtract: ["$$NOW", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30] }] } } }
```

For Date related operations I usually recommend [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), would be this (might be more accurate regarding 30/31 days and DST):

```
{ $match: { myDate: { $lt: moment().subtract(1, 'month').toDate() } } }
```

Comment: Your first way is working =) I will try in aggregation